# MxToolbox says dmarc DNS record is not found despite having one configured with NameCheap

Tags: email, dmarc

My emails get stuffed into spam folder. I havent sent it to anyone but myself.

MxToolbox displays 1 error:

```
dmarc   DNS Record not found
```

These are my namecheap configurations regarding dmarc, dkim and sfp:

```
--RECORD--|-----HOST------------|------------VALUE------------------
TXT         _dmarc.example.com       v=DMARC1; p=quarantine; rua=mailto:postmaster@example.com; ruf=mailto:postmaster@example.com; adkim=r; aspf=r

--RECORD--|-----------------HOST------------|------------VALUE------------------
TXT         dkim._domainkey.example.com     v=DKIM1; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCCiQKBgQCWCxZvgXCarXM9zOX/uXn693UYIuaBkQQ0t7o/lLrbrsQcHqKolwLHAKbbsJnPvTLe5nOKqNt1CiF/0dq9NoTOVyrhaLK/d8SfXIuBbqj7e7eee1JLiadXROhhScb0940mYmql8LvwoSjZopWLN/c5z65o4ObW97y5XV6SSrzgXQIDAQAB

--RECORD--|-----------------HOST------------|------------VALUE------------------
TXT                      @                 v=spf1 a mx ip4:IPHERE -all
```

I am not getting it, why does mxtoolbox think I don't have a dmarc record? Is there anything else I need to do to make dmarc operational?

Comment: What's the domain name in question?

Comment: I am not sure if I am allowed to make it public how incapable our company's developer team is :D I replaced it with example.com. Insert here whatever you want.

Comment: I read through the [common problems with dmarc](https://dmarc.org/2016/07/common-problems-with-dmarc-records/) and didn't see anything obvious that applies to your case.   My guess is that the DNS records just need time to propagate.  Since you asked this question, did it start working?   How long did you wait before trying?

Answer (score 5):

According to  Namecheap's [documentation](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/317/2237/how-do-i-add-txtspfdkimdmarc-records-for-my-domain) on TXT records:

> **Note**: the domain name itself should not be included to the Host field.

Consequently, enter

- `dkim._domainkey` instead of `dkim._domainkey.example.com` in your DKIM entry's "Host" field and
- `_dmarc` instead of `_dmarc.example.com` in the respective field for DMARC.

I've had this issue with DMARC for my own site's DNS records with Namecheap—removing the domain name made the DMARC entry show up in the MxToolBox [diagnostic](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=dmarc%3acountingto.one&run=toolpage).

Comment: I can confirm this works. I use "myprefix._domainkey" for DKIM record and just "_dmarc" for DMARC record. I used http://www.appmaildev.com/en/dkim to validate it works.

Answer (score 0):

The domain name must not be appended to _dmarc  or dkim._domainkey

Comment: Can you add a reason to this, or some sort of explanation or evidence?

Comment: See the above answer. I was able to confirm "_dmarc" worked.